# Getting twitter api to return search results instead of results summary

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm using requests to grab tweets from a geographically bounded area. When I try to print the results, I get what looks like the summary of the results rather than the results themselves. My code is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import pprint


consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key=""
access_token_secret=""
access_token=""
header_auth=True

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json'

headeroauth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
                     access_key, access_token_secret,
                     signature_type='auth_header')  

query_params = { 'q': 'the',
                 'geocode': '33.520661, -86.80249, 50mi' 
               }

response = requests.get(url, auth=headeroauth, params=query_params)
data = response.json()
pprint.pprint(data)
```

And the response I get back is:

```
{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 15, u'completed_in': 0.025000000000000001,
u'max_id_str': u'349363977614143489', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'
since_id=349363977614143489&q=the&geocode=33.520661%2C%20
86.80249%2C%2050mi&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'the', u'max_id': 349363977614143489}, u'statuses': []}
```

How do I set it up to return the actual content of the tweets? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [twitter API's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) when you use "search", you got this dict object and in `statuses` key you should have a list of tweets according to your search options. Be sure that tweets in statuses are dict objects too, and its content are in `text` key

Comment: How would I go about making sure tweets in statuses are there and set as dict objects? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your geocode parameter and it should return statuses:

```
query_params = { 'q': 'the',
                 'geocode': '33.520661,-86.80249,50mi' 
               }
```

Also check out [the Twitter dev console](https://dev.twitter.com/console) for testing out your queries.